# Swagger path variable that includes rest of path

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I am trying to create a swagger spec that encapsulates the remaining path as a variable. The spec path looks like `/config/{path}`. I would like the path variable to be any arbitrary path such as: `path/to/my/key`. Currently, it thinks `to/my/key` is a separate route. Is it possible is Swagger to grab the remaining path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger: wildcard path parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335178/swagger-wildcard-path-parameters)