# Swagger: wildcard path parameters

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have an API which allows any arbitrary path to be passed in, for example all of these:

- `/api/tags`
- `/api/tags/foo`
- `/api/tags/foo/bar/baz`

Are valid paths. I tried to describe it as follows:

```
 /tags{tag_path}:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: tag_path
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
          default: "/"
```

However, https://generator.swagger.io encodes slashes in the path, so it doesn't work. So is there a way to describe my API in Swagger?

Comment: We have the same issue - so far no luck! I'll update here if we find anything.

Comment: Looks like this isn't supported in Swagger 2.0 (or even 3.0!) and there's a big discussion about why here: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/892#issuecomment-281170254

Seems silly as it seems really common to do this.

Comment: I just noticed that you are the one that opened the issue I referenced! Haha

Comment: Yeah, nice :) Thanks for being in the same boat, huh.

Comment: Found a workaround which is acceptable for me, see my answer below.

Comment: same problem. ditching swagger because of this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not supported as of OpenAPI 3.1, and I have to resort to a workaround.

If I have a path `/tags{tag_path}` and I enter something like this as `tag_path`: `/foo/bar`, then the actual query request URL will be: `/tags%2Ffoo%2Fbar`. So, I just added support for that on my backend: the endpoint handler for `/tags*` urldecodes the path (which is `%2Ffoo%2Fbar`), and it becomes `/foo/bar` again.

Yes, a hack, but it works, and it's better than nothing. In my case, tag names can't contain the `/` character, so there's no conflict. Your mileage may vary, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a framework like Connexion, chances are it does support a wildcard path parameter (even though it is not in the OpenAPI spec).

Here is an example for Connexion.

```yaml
paths:
  /pages/{path}:
    get:
     # (...)
      parameters:
        - name: "path"
          in: path
          description: "Remainder of path, including slashes."
          schema:
            type: string
            format: path
```

The difference is the [`format: path`](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#wildcard-path-parameters) added.